# Can you translate utf8 file to ascii with non-ascii characters replaced by tex-macro?

Tags: unicode

The title says it all. I have a unicode (utf-8) file which contains some non-ascii characters, e.g. "ö" and translate it into an ascii-file where the non-ascii characters are replaced with tex-macros, in this case `\"o`.

Any ideas? I found [this converter](http://98.245.80.27/tcpc/scripts/uniquote) but it's only to HTML.

Comment: Why not use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to be able to use utf8 characters?

Comment: I don't want it for latex but for handling my bibtex-database. Many tools do not treat utf-8 correctly

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186733/a-utility-for-auto-formatting-bib-files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can take a look at utf2any
http://www.ctan.org/pkg/utf2any
not sure if it does what you want

or maybe some other package from one of these lists
http://www.ctan.org/keyword/encodings
http://www.ctan.org/characterization/primary/tools/convert-formats/

generally i would say it is preferrable to use a completly utf8 capable toolchain instead of converting utf8 files to non-utf8

edit: i see you want for utf-8 for you bibliography: there are utf-8 capable tools available for this. instead of bibtex you can use biblatex and biber - switching is easy! i have lots of äöüß and more in my .bib-file and it works just great. as a start you can try something like

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Bibfile}
```

Comment: I would appreciate to know which solution you have found. I also want a command which would transform ö into \"o...

Comment: Note that `\bibliography` is obsolete and replaced by `\addbibresource{Bibfile.bib}` (mandatory suffix) (cf. manual, sec. 3.5.1).

Answer (score 3):

With `biblatex` and `biber`, you can set the `biblatex` options

```
bibencoding=utf8
texencoding=ascii
```

And `biber` will reencode your utf8 bib file into TeX macros in the `.bbl`

See the `biber` manual for details and options